# Agrupar linhas com null

Tags: sql-server

Como posso retirar as linhas nulas e deixar somente as datas uma do lado da outra;

Exemplo: 48010255 | 2016-06-10 07:46:41.573 | null | 2016-06-09 12:36:22.243

```
SELECT
     cod_pista
     ,DT_ENTRADA    = IIF(ST_TIPO_ACAO = 'E' AND CO_DESTINO = 7888,[DATA],NULL)
     ,DT_SAIDA      = IIF(ST_TIPO_ACAO = 'S' AND CO_ORIGEM = 7888,[DATA],NULL)
     ,DT_ENVIO      = IIF(ST_TIPO_ACAO = 'S' AND CO_DESTINO = 7888,[DATA],NULL)
FROM tmp_2 TR
```

[image: resultado]

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas com SQL Standard não é possível resolver essa. Se faz necessário usar funções analíticas para analisarmos os dados que virão na próximo linha, ou que vieram na linha anterior.

Este é um caso para se usar a função analítica `LAG` do SQL Server.

```
LAG (scalar_expression [,offset] [,default])  
    OVER ( [ partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause )
```

A função `LAG` consegue "enxergar" o valor da próxima linha da consulta, com isso podemos tomar algumas decisões.

No caso da sua consulta, acredito que se fizer algo assim:

```
WITH TR (SELECT id,
                cod_pista,
                DT_ENTRADA = IIF(ST_TIPO_ACAO = 'E' AND CO_DESTINO = 7888, [DATA], NULL),
                DT_SAIDA   = IIF(ST_TIPO_ACAO = 'S' AND CO_ORIGEM  = 7888, [DATA], NULL),
                DT_ENVIO   = IIF(ST_TIPO_ACAO = 'S' AND CO_DESTINO = 7888, [DATA], NULL)
           FROM tmp_2)



SELECT DISTINCT
       cod_pista,
       DT_ENTRADA = ISNULL(DT_ENTRADA, LAG(DT_ENTRADA, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id)),
       DT_SAIDA = ISNULL(DT_SAIDA, LAG(DT_SAIDA, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id)),
       DT_ENVIO = ISNULL(DT_ENVIO, LAG(DT_ENVIO, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id))
 FROM tr
```

Veja como fica o retorno dessa consulta, certamente precisará de alguns ajustes de design, mas vc já terá seus dados "agrupados" na mesma linha.

Comment: Thiago, muito obrigado. Ficou perfeito..

Comment: @DanSan, não esqueça de marcar a resposta como a qual te atendeu. :)

Comment: Feito.. Obrigado Thiago.